# Can I use ''with'' with it?

Tags: prepositions

For example someone sent me an invoice for products that I bought but I see that the price is higher than the price they offered me. In this case can I say him the sentence above by using with? Can it be understandabele?

> I received it with the price higher than your offer.

I know there are the better ways to describe this situation but I wonder if my sentence grammatically correct in terms of using “with”.

Comment: "The price quoted on the invoice is more than I was expecting to pay."

Comment: To get or buy something *for* a certain price is more idiomatic than *with*.

Comment: Are you asking about how to use the word "with", or how to choose the correct preposition, or how to express a complaint about this situation?

Comment: I am asking if “with” is good choice in this sentence. I know this sentence is not best choice to describe this situation.